# I use $_POST and i get empty values

Tags: php, mysql, post

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "db";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Pelates";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$count=$result->num_rows;  
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table><tr><th></th><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th></tr>";
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td><input type='hidden' id='num' name='number[]' value='".$row["number"]."'/></td><td><input type='text' id='nam' name='name[]' value='".$row["name"]."'/></td><td><input type='text' id='surnam' name='surname[]' value='".$row["surname"]."'/></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++){
$sql = "UPDATE Pelates SET name='".$name[$i]."', surname='".$surname[$i]."' WHERE number=".intval($number[$i])."";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "Update ok";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
}
mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a table with my records and i'm trying to update them all, but when i press the submit button all fields updated with an empty field.
This is the code i use. I put this code in a joomla article and i'm using the sourcerer.

Comment: Can you post the code used in order to submit the POST operation to the PHP file?

Comment: ^ that would be too easy.

Comment: We need a challenge @joncloud

Comment: I've my money on inputs not being treated as arrays, and/or no name attributes, no post method in form. But this, is guesswork, just like the unknown form.

Comment: and my 5 mins. span of attention has just run out. Good luck with that. Magic answers only happen on Halloween and we're nowhere near Oct. 31st, now are we?

Comment: Take this for the pain. Mike Mangini played it perfectly even in audition.

Comment: you are probably right about the inputs. i just started using php and i'm trying to update the tables through my joomla site but i don't know how.

Comment: I have updated the code above!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `</form>` element is closing the form prior to rendering any of the `<input>` elements.

Comment: Thank you very much!! :)